# Does Wheatley actually look for my dead body after an hour?

Tags: portal-2

Near the beginning of the game (Test Chamber 02 to be precise), right before you find the single-portal gun, you fall down a shaft and into some water. Wheatley asks

> Can you see the portal gun?

He then continues:

> Also, are you alive? That's important, should have asked that first.
>
> I'm--do you know what I'm going to do? I'm going to work on the assumption that you're still alive and I'm just going to wait for you up ahead.
>
> I'll wait--I'll wait one hour. Then I'll come back and, assuming I can locate your dead body, I'll bury you. Alright? Brilliant! Go team! See you in an hour! Hopefully! If you're not... dead.
>   - [Portal Wiki](http://theportalwiki.com/wiki/Wheatley_voice_lines#Test_Chamber_02)

I didn't really have the time, but if you actually stand there for an hour, will he come? I realize this is pushing the bounds of game development, but it *is* Valve we're talking about here.

Comment: Well there IS an achievement for waiting an hour in one of the test chambers IIRC..."You've proved your point" or something

Comment: No.  How would he?  He is still on his track.

Comment: @bwarner Maybe his track leads down there. I know what you're asking: "Why wouldn't he just come immediately then?" Because he's *Wheatley*. When scientists spend decades making something stupid...

Comment: @Ben: That achievement requires you to wait like 30 seconds.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

No, unfortunately, he never comes back to look for you (I tried waiting). It's not like there's anything down there that'd actually kill you within an hour anyway, and there doesn't appear to be anything in the script to the effect of him traveling back and calling for you, after that line. Still, rather unfortunate.

Comment: I'm impressed you tried :P

Comment: Good thing I play in windowed mode, so I get to do other things while waiting (like... answering questions!) :)

Comment: +1 and accepted for SCIENCE! Had you tried it before, or did you try in response to this question?

Comment: I tried it way back. If I only did in response to your question, I wouldn't have been able to post my findings within less than 10 minutes of you asking ;)

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro *facepalm* touche...

Comment: Valve, I'm disappointed. Fix this bug!

Comment: What a shame; this would've been an awesome case of [The Dev Team Thinks of Everything](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheDevTeamThinksOfEverything).

Comment: @Nolonar: Exactly :/